# Possible to develop J2ME applications on IPhone, Android (HTCs..), Samsungs etc?

Tags: iphone, android, java-me

I know for a fact that most Blackberry Handsets is Java enabled and supports J2ME development but i haven't found any useful information on the same topic regarding IPHone, Androids etc..

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone only supports apps written in HTML ('web apps') or Objective-C/C++ ('native apps'). It won't support J2ME applications.

Neither will Android (at least via the marketplace), but because Android apps are written in Java it will be probably be easier for you (if you're coming from a Java background) to get started on that platform.

Comment: There are some frameworks in development which can provide j2me vm on top of android. If am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: any help would be much considered. thanks for your contribution

Comment: Nowadays there are plenty of options for Android, including a great one I've been using for a year or two now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321703/can-we-run-j2me-apps-on-android-phones

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can run J2ME applications (not everything will work correctly though). I don't know details of how this is done, but I just downloaded JAR file and it was started fine on my HTC Evo 4G.

Note, however, that J2ME and it's applications were mostly designed for 12-key phone keyboards, and on touch screen they are not too usable.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success getting Java application running on iOS using XCode and a cross-compiler known as XMLVM... Keep in mind my success was only on an emulator. Not running the app on the actual device. Though, I suppose the difference varies only in some aspects.

P.S. My iPhone was jailbroken at the time and running 5.1.1