# Running J2me apps on Android phones

Tags: java-me

Is it possible to run J2ME apps on Android phones? If so, what is the installation procedure?

Otherwise, is it possible to convert .jad files to .apk? In this case, what is the procedure.

(I have already tested the procedure offered by [netmite](http://www.netmite.com/) but it doesn't seem to work.)

Answer (score 2):

Using this site http://www.netmite.com/android/srv/2.0/getapk.php you can convert your J2ME application   in to Android Application. You need to just supply your .Jad & .Jar file in it and it will generate Android's executable file .apk for you.

However in it doesn't able to convert all the feature of Java ME to Android, but basics can be easily converted.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a good JavaME emulator for Android for a long time, and finally found one. This here is what you need:

http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/

No doubt the best there is for Android.

**Added 15th January 2016:**
Reply from the author of phoneME, Davy Preuveneers, in regards to the Android 5.0+ issue commented by Álvaro Gutiérrez:

> Hi,
>
> I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1, and the
>   "phoneME Advanced - Foundation Profile + MIDP FullHD Resolution" build
>   seems to run just fine on this device.
>
> Also, following this thread
>   [Position Independent Executables and Android Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498776/position-independent-executables-and-android-lollipop),
>   I ran:
>
> `$ readelf -l libcvm.so  | grep -i "file type"`
>
> and it reports:
>
> `Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)`
>
> So according to the website this is OK.
>
> However, for the CDC and Foundation profiles (console like
>   applications), there is indeed an issue where you get this error:
>
> "Error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported"
>
> However, for those 2 profile I call a native executables and redirect
>   the native stdout/stderr streams to Android, whereas for the MIDP dual
>   stack I load a library and create a complicated wrapper to get things going.
>
> I can recompile with -fPIE and -pie options but will then end up with
>   binaries that are no longer backwards compatible with devices running
>   Android 4.0 and below. That is why I added some additional builds to my
>   website for Android 5+ devices:
>
> http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/10
>
> Best regards,
>   Davy

Comment: does not work on Android 5.0+ until updated (uses position-dependent executable files not allowed to run on such systems).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will mail the author and let him know.

Comment: I have received a reply from the author of phoneME,, and have added it to my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try phoneME, netmite j2me app runner, jblend, jbed like jeme emulators in android. For now, phoneME is the best. you can get various version of phoneME here http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme 
You also need OI file manager to select files in phoneME.

A complete guide can be found here http://w3epic.com/run-java-apps-j2me-on-android-devices-guide/ for rest of other emulators (if you want to try).

@dennis
I got it, thanks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

MicroEmu open source project hasn't been mentioned yet, and here it goes: https://code.google.com/p/microemu/