# Does j2me support SHA-2 for signing an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, java-me, code-signing, sha2

A provider is developing an android application and told me that SHA2 is not supported because they are using J2ME. Is this really true? I did some google searching and didn't find anything about this.

Another thing that worry me is that they are using J2ME to develop an Android application. Is this a good idea? Isn't more secure to develop using native Android and not Java Microedition?

Thanks in advance.

Best!

Comment: J2ME and "Android Java" are two different things.
But you can run J2ME MIDlets on Android using an emulator like e.g. phoneME. All your users will need to install this on their phone then.

Answer (score 0):

J2ME can't be used at all for develop an Android app.

According [this page](https://www.digicert.com/sha-2-compatibility.htm), Android does support SHA-2 on 2.3+ version, at least at the browser side. I didn't understand very well the part of "sign the application with SHA-2"

Answer (score 0):

J2ME can be used to develop an Android app. In fact, it isn't the best way but this provider is doing that. Check this out

[Running J2me apps on Android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321703/can-we-run-j2me-apps-on-android-phones)

The second question is about code signing certificate. Is necessary to sign the application with a code signing certificate. This certificate can use SHA1 or SHA2 (there are another options). My question is about J2ME and the support of SHA2 certificates.

Hope this clarify my question.

Thanks

Comment: Code signing was done with J2ME to avoid security-popups.
For Android there are no security-popups, because the user grants all permissions when installing.
If you're developing an app for Android in J2ME to be used with phoneME emulator, then you don't need to sign your MIDlet. There are no security popups in phoneME.

Comment: Is an android application and the provider user J2ME. Android Apps need to be signed http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Yes, but you're not creating an Android app. You are creating a J2ME app (known as MIDlets). They require the Android user to have a J2ME emulator installed, like phoneME. phoneME is the Android app, not your J2ME app.